# How to get return type DONE in keyBoard numberpad mode

Tags: iphone

We should get DONE button in Numberpad when we have

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. I have added semi-transparent background and additional button which are hidden by default. Then I added following methods:

```
-(IBAction)startEditing{
    [blackBg setHidden:FALSE];
    [doneEditingButton setHidden:FALSE];
}

-(IBAction)doneEditing{
    [blackBg setHidden:TRUE];
    [doneEditingButton setHidden:TRUE];
    [someTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

All you need to do now is to connect UITextFiled action "Editing did begin" with startEditing method and a UIButton's "Touch down" with doneEditing.